# History of group theory character tables (as used in physics and chemistry)

Tags: mathematics, terminology, theoretical-physics, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does anyone know who started using the symbols A, B, E, T  (First column, left) for showing irreducible representations of symmetry groups? In older maths books I see capital gamma. Herein A= totally symmetric, B= anti-symmetric with respect to rotation, E= doubly degenerate, T is triply degenerate irreducible representation. The symbols in the top row are due to Schonflies (D4h, C, S, Sigma).

Many books/ webpages claim that Mulliken started this symbols, and they are indeed called Mulliken symbols http://www.cup.uni-muenchen.de/ch/compchem/geom/point3.html, however, many other physicists were using A, B,  E and T symbolism at the same time (1930s). The letter C was not used. It appears that mathematicians must be using these symbols before that but I could not find any example. Is anyone aware of the history of character tables such as the one shown here? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mulliken credits [**Georg Placzek**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Placzek) in his autobiography ([1989](https://books.google.com/books?id=2eDrCAAAQBAJ&ots=klOUqVqu5v&pg=PA90&dq=Placzek), p. 90). According to T. Oka ([2011](https://doi.org/10.1002/9780470749593.hrs074))([pdf](http://fermi.uchicago.edu/publications/PDF/oka270.pdf)):

> Placzek (1934) introduced the currently used symbols of irreducible representations such as A (symmetric), B (antisymmetric), E (“entartet”, doubly degenerate), F (triply degenerate), subscript 1 and 2 (to specify symmetry with respect to C<sub>2</sub>) and superscript ′ and ′′ (to specify symmetry with respect to σ), etc. While a little unsystematic, the much-needed nomenclature was immediately adopted by theorists like Teller, Tisza, Mulliken, Wilson, and others, and has become the fixture in molecular spectroscopy.
>
> ---
>
> Placzek, G. (1934) Rayleigh-Streuung und Raman-effekt. *Marx’s Handbuch der Radiologie*, **VI**, (Part II), 209–374.

Comment: Thank you very much. Glad to know that he mentioned that in his autobiography.